# Extracting an integer from a line with the help of linux script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file, one of whose line contains:

> number    8

how can i use sed, grep or whatever linux script to find out what **integer** is there in front of the line that starts with "number"?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$1=="number"{print $2}' file
```

Comment: Thanks man. Does the command mean to print field 2 where field 1 == number?

Answer (score 2):

Use awk:

```
cat ./file.text | awk '/number/ {print $2}'
```

Comment: I prefer using cat, makes the command more readable, and portable. You can just replace the cat with whatever generates the output you want to parse.

Comment: with cat, you add 3 more characters. Plus, you create one extra pipe process. Portable?? in what sense? And providing the file to awk's input is not/or less portable?

Answer (score 1):

use grep and cut, this will return only the number

```
cat ./file.txt | grep number | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `awk`:

```
awk '/number/ {print $2}' < ./file.txt
```

It's a single command, which some prefer. If it's a large file, you may prefer the `cat | grep | cut`-way, as the three programs run in separate processes.

Comment: if its a large file, use just awk!. cat + grep + cut +whatever is expensive operation on large files. Also, there is no need for redirection. just pass the file directly to awk.